# How to install R-environment on Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, r

I am following this tutorial here to install R on Jupiter notebook [text](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/navigator/tutorials/create-r-environment/)
when I select the packages, I could not find the mentioned version of Python and R checkbox is not clickable. Could anyone advise how to bypass this?[[image]](https://i.s[image]tack.imgur.com/ndIfW.png)

I wanted to install R on jupiter notebook but the selection is not even clickable. I am using macOS